# Java | calling method of a child class

Tags: java, class, methods, derived-class

I have a class called HourlyEmployee that extends a class called Employee.

The HourlyEmployee has a method to getHoursWorked that does not exist in the Employee class.

Now in my main class I have an array of different types of employees (both hourly and salary) and I am trying to run a for loop that grabs the hours worked of each HourlyEmployee.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            if (employees[i] instanceof HourlyEmployee) {
                if (employees[i].getHoursWorked() > 80) {
                    System.out.println(employees[i].getFullName() + ": " + (employees[i]getHoursWorked() - 80));
                }
            }
        }
```

It throws errors when I attempt to call getHoursWorked in the if statement as well as the println.

I can provide additional context if needed, just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Try casting: `((HourlyEmployee)employees[i]).getHoursWorked()`. In your code you're working on  `Employee` objects that doesn't have that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `employees[i]` to `HourlyEmployee`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (employees[i] instanceof HourlyEmployee) {
        HourlyEmployee employee = (HourlyEmployee) employees[i];
        if (employee.getHoursWorked() > 80) {
            System.out.println(employee.getFullName() + ": " + (employee.getHoursWorked() - 80));
        }
    }
}
```